# Make a text block to have the same vertical space like the footer of page

Tags: css, wordpress

I use Visual Composer and I add a text block.

Here is the code for this:

```
[/vc_column_text][vc_empty_space height="" el_id="" el_class="" css=""][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row css_animation="" row_type="row" use_row_as_full_screen_section="no" type="full_width" angled_section="no" text_align="left" background_image_as_pattern="without_pattern"][vc_column][vc_column_text el_id="" el_class="" css=""]

I am text block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.

[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

How it is possible to make the text block has the whole margin from the left and right? Example to have the vertical space of the page like the footer.

Here an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veyIl.png) of how it is now

Answer (score 0):

In the right in the field Template chose "Full width"